# Symfony 2.1 - problems loading assets and an exception thrown by assetic

Tags: php, exception, twig, symfony-2.1, assetic

This is a bit frustrating.  According to Symfony best practices, a bundle's web assets (images, css, js) should be placed in `src/vendor/path/to/bundle/Resources/public`.  Running `app/console assets:install` copies the contents of that public folder to `web/bundles/bundlename`.  In the official documentation, Twig templates are shown to grab these assets with code like:

```
{% block stylesheets %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('/css/styles.css') }}
{% endblock %}
```

When I try it, instead of magically grabbing my assets from `web/bundles/bundlename/css/styles.css`, it instead just goes for `web/css/styles.css`.  Is this expected behavior?  The official documentation is less than clear about this.

In order to try to combat this issue, I tried embracing assetic's ability to dynamically serve assets.  I tried:

```
{% stylesheets '@mybundle/Resources/public/css/*' %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

But got the following exception:

> An exception has been thrown during the compilation of a template ("You must add mybundle to the assetic.bundle config to use the {% stylesheets %} tag in mybundle:Home:index.html.twig.") in "/home/kevin/www/src/mybundle/Resources/views/Home/index.html.twig

The [official Symfony documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html) makes it appear that it should work out of the box with no configuration necessary.

So, TLDR:

1. Am I not understanding how assets should be loaded?
2. How do I address the assetic exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix the assetic exception you need to configure your bundle in your config.yml like this:

```
assetic:
    bundles: [ MyAwesomeBundle ]
```

The `{{ asset(...) }}` twig function will serve files relative from your web root.

You use `app/console assets:install` to install static assets within your web root and you can later easily point to them using the asset function like this `{{ asset('/mybundle/css/site.css') }}`